# Estimating $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(t\log n)$

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I've been thinking about the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(t\log n)$$ for large $N$. If $t=0$ the case is obvious, but when $t\neq 0$ can this sum be bounded? I presume it diverges weaker than just $N$; probably something like $N^\epsilon$ for some $0<\epsilon<1$. Equivalently the sum $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{it \log n} \right|$$
could be considered. I've been thinking about Koksma, but not sure how to apply it here.

Any ideas?

Comment: My first thought is Euler-Maclaurin, since $\cos(\log(ax))$ has an elementary integral, but I haven't put pencil to paper.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is wrong. If it was right, then $t\log n$ would be equidistributed, according to Weyl's criterion, but it isn't.

See [Show that $\{a \log n \}$ is not equidistributed for any $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950100/show-that-a-log-n-is-not-equidistributed-for-any-a)

Edit: on second reading, the question I posted doesn't have an answer and the connection is really not that obvious. So let's just prove it directly without reference to anything but basic calculus:

You can replace the sum by the integral

$$
\int_{1}^{N} \cos(t \log x) dx =\frac{1}{2} N (\cos \log N + \sin \log N)
$$
with error $$
|\epsilon_N|\leq \sum^N |\cos'(\xi_n)| t/n
$$
The integral grows like $N$ the error like $\log N$. This disproves your $N^{\epsilon}$ guess but falls just short of showing actual linear growth.

Comment: Hey, what is $\xi_n$? Are you sure using an integral for estimation is valid here? The function is everything, but monotone.

Comment: I mean, doesn't for example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1-it}$ converge for $t\neq 0$, or at least be bounded by a constant?

Comment: I didn't even think to try to integrate it. I just thought of considering the sums from $e^{\pi m/t}$ to $e^{\pi(m+1)/t}$.

Comment: $\left|\sum_{n=N/2}^N e^{it \log n} \right|$ is about $N/2$ for $N$ much larger than $t$ since the terms are close to each other; $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1-it}$ doesn't exist, but oscillates finitely for each $t$ but while the partial sums are bounded in $N$ they are not bounded in $t$ so not sure what is the relevance since we alredy know that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{it \log n} \right| \le N$

Comment: @Conrad: Can you prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1-it}$ converges? The relevance is that I thought both sums can actually be related by $$\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-1-it} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-it} + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-it}\right) \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \, .$$
So if $\sum_{n=1}^N  n^{-it}$ could be bounded by something like $N^\epsilon$ with $0<\epsilon<1$, the first objective would follow from the other. But apparently that is not the case...

Comment: Since $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-it} = {\cal O}(N)$, the second term is not clear if it is bounded by a constant, so nothing is won...
PS: Mind my small mistake in the previous comment. "prove that it is bounded by a constant", not "converge".

Comment: @Diger the partial sums of $n^{-1-it}$ oscillate wildly and are bounded by a function in $t$ that oscillates wildly and goes to $\infty$ with $t$ ; the details are in chapter 3 (expression for the partial sums) and 8 ( behaviour at infinity in $t$) of Titchmarsh RZ book and are classic

Comment: Can you say what page you mean explicitly?

Comment: page 50 equation just before 3.6 shows that $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-1-it}-\zeta(1+it)=i\frac{N^{-it}}{t} + O(\frac{t}{N}), |t| \ge 2$ say, and then in chapter 8 it is shown that $\zeta(1+it) = \Omega \log \log t$ which implies that the oscillation of the sum $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-1-it}$ is unbounded in $t$ - pick $t$ large satisfying the $\Omega$ result quoted and $N$ slightly larger than $t$ in the above sum so $O(t/N)$ is small

Answer (score 0):

Since the above sum is quite famous (though the interesting part of it happens when $t$ is large wr $N$, say $t \ge N^2$ when appropriately formulated bounds on it are equivalent to the Lindelof Hypothesis) let's show the easy result that if we fix $t \ne 0$, then for any $N$ there is a $M(N,t)$ s.t.

$S_{N,M}=\sum_{n=N}^{N+M-1} e^{it \log n}$ satisfies:

$|S_{N,M(N,t)}| \ge \frac{N}{2t+2}, N > t+1$,

which immediately implies that no uniform bound $|S_N|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{it \log n} \right| \le C(t,f)Nf(N), f(N) \to 0$ can exist for any function $0<f(N) \to 0, N \to \infty$ or if you want in shorthand that $S_N=o(N)$ cannot hold for fixed $t$ and $N \to \infty$

Fix $t>0$ as the sum for negative $t$ is obtained by conjugation. Integrating $f(x)=x^{it-1}$ on the interval $N, N+k$, $|e^{it\log(N+k)}-e^{it\log N}| \le \frac{k(t+1)}{N}$, so $||S_{N,M}|-M|\le \frac{(t+1)M(M-1)}{2N} \le \frac{N}{2(t+1)}$for $M(N,t)=\frac{N}{t+1}, N >t+1$, so $M>1$

But this clearly implies the stated result:

$|S_{N,M(N,t)}| \ge \frac{N}{2t+2}, N > t+1$