# Equidistribution of scalar multiples of a given sequence

Tags: reference-request, uniform-distribution, p-adic-number-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n\rightarrow+\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Write $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ for the projection map. Is it true that for almost all $t\in\mathbb{R}$(in the usual Lebesgue measure), the sequence $(\phi(tx_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is equidistributed in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$(in the quotient measure)? For example, for $x_n=nx$ for any $x>0$, we know this is true from the [Equidistribution Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem). Moreover [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl%27s_criterion) gives the equidistribution for a *fixed* value $t$.

More generally, write $\mathbb{A}$ for the adele ring of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then for a place $v$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, we have the composition map $\phi\colon\mathbb{Q}_v\rightarrow\mathbb{A}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\backslash\mathbb{A}/\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\simeq\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ where the first map is the canonical embedding, the second map is the projection and the last map is a homeomorphism of topological groups. Given a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{Q}_v$ such that $|x_n|_v\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Is it true that for almost all $t\in\mathbb{Q}_v$, the sequence $(\phi(tx_n))_n$ is equidistributed in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$? Again for $v=p$ a finite place and $x_n=1/p^n$, we know this is true thanks to a theorem of Ferrero and Washington (see Proposition 2 of [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971116?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)).

I would also like to know whether we can say something if we replace 'equidistributed' by 'dense'.

I would appreciate if someone could point me to some references or indicate whether these results hold or not. By the way, I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask such questions. If not, I will delete my post.

*Added*: thanks to the comments below, I realised that my questions about equidistribution have a negative answer, for example, for $v=\infty$ and $x_n=\ln(n)$ or a sequence that grows very slowly. On the other hand, one can check that using Weyl's criterion, for any strictly increasing integer sequence $(x_n)_n$, the answer to the question in the case $v=\infty$ is positive.

Comment: For arbitrary sequences $x_n \to + \infty$ I think the answer is no? See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3780135/12880); take e.g. $x_n = \log(n)$ and we don't have equidistribution for *any* $t \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: For your first question: have you checked with $x_n=\ln{\ln{n}}$? This looks like it could be a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out this counter example to me! I did not realise that Weyl's criterion already contains a possible counter-example.